# Lighting on a mesh is dark and inconsistent. How do I fix this?

Tags: mesh, lighting

[image: The character on the left should not look like she is now in the shadows]

Hello. I am creating a FNaF Fan-game of my own, and I wanted to create a concept trailer witch shows some ideas I have for the game before I make it.

However, in the cycles Render Engine, the character on the left (Sweetheart), has some messed up lighting compared to the character on the right (Sweetie). It looks like shes in the darkness even though there is a spot light pointed straight at her.

I was following this tutorial on how to create Scratched plastic materials( [Procedural Scratched Plastic (Blender Tutorial) by Ryan King Art](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l0whu3494_c) ) to make Sweetie's suit look more detailed. I believe that I messed up by simply copying and pasting all of the shader and texture nodes over to Sweetheart's Materials so that I didn't have to remake the shader nodes all over again for her character model. The models for both characters are not high poly, both of them are about 113,000 vertices and 110,000 faces each.

What can I do to make the lighting look better on Sweetheart's model, and what can I do to prevent this issue from happening again? because this is bugging me a lot more that it should.

Comment: You would need to use a broader and/or larger light source. Currently it is as if you are using a spot light.

Comment: As @Dontwalk said, your light isn't very broad. If you look at the wall behind your characters the, light and shadow, you can see that the spotlight merely shines on the upper body (on both characters I would say, only that you can't see down to the feet in darkness on the right one). Apart from that I don't think the left one looks much darker than the other, only that this more brown/earthy color scheme isn't as vibrant as the pink one.

Comment: For re-using the shader and textures: there's no need for copying and pasting all nodes manually to a new material. Just give the new character the same material. Then in the _Shader Editor_ you can see the number 2 next to the material's name. If you click on this number, the material gets duplicated (you can see it by changing the name from e.g. "Material" to "Material.001" and the number disappearing). Now the second character has its own material based on the first and you can edit it without changing the other.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann OML thank you for the advice! I needed to learn this so badly! I can't thank you enough!